# Butterknife unable to bind views after dividing project into modules

Tags: android, butterknife

I have turned on `ButterKnife.setDebug(BuildConfig.DEBUG)`

What's happening is that classes that have always worked now cannot find the bindings for views. After calling `ButterKnife.bind(this);` the view is still null and when I check the logs I see the following:

```
16401-16401 D/ButterKnife: Looking up binding for com.mobile.myapp.presentation.view.controllers.login.activities.WelcomeActivity
16401-16401 D/ButterKnife: Not found. Trying superclass com.mobile.myapp.presentation.view.base.myappBaseMvpActivity
16401-16401 D/ButterKnife: Not found. Trying superclass com.hannesdorfmann.mosby.mvp.MvpActivity
16401-16401 D/ButterKnife: Not found. Trying superclass android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
16401-16401 D/ButterKnife: MISS: Reached framework class. Abandoning search.
```

So I thought it could be the annotation processor dependency. I added the following to every module:

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

But still same issue and no views get bindings, there null.  I realize I can switch to Kotlin but I have a lot of classes that are in Java and would prefer to bind using Butterknife. What am I missing. These issues occur at runtime.

Here is an example class that is null binding:

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends myappBaseMvpActivity<WelcomeView, WelcomePresenter> implements WelcomeView {

    @Nullable
    @BindView(R.id.btn_showlogin)
    Button btn_login; //this is null


    @Nullable
    @BindView(R.id.pager)
    ViewPager mViewPager; //this is null, why ?

    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        mViewPager.setAdapter(new WelcomeIntroPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    }
//...
}
```

UPDATE: I CONVERTED MY CODE TO KOTLIN TO RESOLVE THESE KIND OF ISSUES BUT STILL ID LIKE TO KNOW WHY BUTTERKNIFE FAILS.

Comment: Did you add `apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'` to the corresponding modules?

Comment: i put the following in every module:   implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1' .  but the stuff im trying to access it in my app module which already had this dependency anyway. i tried clean and rebuild. everything was fine until i seperated the project into modules.

Answer (score 0):

File-> Settings -> Plugins -> Android ButterKnife Zelezny

Please Follow this steps and install plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;
import this above class or check
```

https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife#download

Answer (score 0):

If you have kotlin dependencies than you should use kapt instead of annotationProcessor

```
//View Binding and Logging
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

The above if for AndroidX , but you can use it with the version that you have. Just use kapt!
Also if you have updated your libraries to androidx or you have gradle plugin update, then you should use the latest version of the library!
let me know if this helps.